# Alterar output de um input type time

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um form com um input do type="time", quando eu clico no submit a url envia os dados assim: 

`hrentrada=HH%3AMM&hrsaida=HH%3AMM`. 

 Gostaria que mandasse assim: 

`hrentrada=HHMM&hrsaida=HHMM`. 

 Alguém sabe como manipular isso?

```
<form name="teste" method="GET" action="index.html"> 
   <input type="time" name="hrentrada"style="width:70px" maxlength="4 required>
   <input type="time" name="hrsaida"style="width:70px" maxlength="4" required>
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

de preferencia so com html e no máximo javascript puro

Comment: O browser faz isso de propósito para evitar ter `:` no URL. Podes descodificar isso com JavaScript usando `decodeURIComponent('HH%3AMM&hrsaida=HH%3AMM')`... mas o servidor deve receber isso corretamente. Estás a usar um servidor?

Comment: Eu queria justamente tirar esse %3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada impede de você tratar a informação no destino (index.html). Porém se for uma restrição do seu projeto você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="time" name="hrentrada_get"style="width:70px" maxlength="4">
<input type="time" name="hrsaida_get" style="width:70px" maxlength="4">
<form name="teste" method="GET" action="index.html" onsubmit="return ajustarHora()"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="hrentrada">
   <input type="hidden" name="hrsaida">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<script>
function ajustarHora(){
    $("input[name='hrentrada']").val($("input[name='hrentrada_get']").val().replace(":",""));
    $("input[name='hrsaida']").val($("input[name='hrsaida_get']").val().replace(":",""));

  return false;
}
</script>
```

Nesta solução você vai precisar validar o preenchimento dos campos que estão fora do form e de acordo com sua necessidade fazer o `ajustarHora()` retornar `true` ou `false` para enviar ou não os dados.

Segue link de exemplo funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/76wzqupt/2/